# parsing lines with yacc and readline

Tags: c++, parsing, bison, readline, yacc

I'm starting to write a light interpreter for a single language for managing graphs. I'a using flex and bison and I have some problems defining the grammar.

For now, I only just want to parse three single commands:

1. `load "file-name"`
2. `save "file-name"`
3. `exit`

This is the grammar in yacc:

```
%{

# include <iostream>  

  using namespace std;

 int yylex(void);
 void yyerror(char const *);

%}

%token LOAD SAVE RIF COD EXIT STRCONST VARNAME 

%%

input: line
;

line: cmd_unit '\n'
{
  cout << "PARSED LINE with EOL" << endl; 
}
| cmd_unit
{
  cout << "PARSED LINE without EOL" << endl; 
}
;  

cmd_unit: LOAD STRCONST
{
  cout << "PARSED LOAD" << endl;
}
| SAVE STRCONST 
{
  cout << "PARSED SAVE" << endl;
}
| EXIT { }
;

%%
```

Now this is the lexer and the very simple repl in lex:

```
%{

# include <net-parser.H>
# include "test.tab.h"


  YYSTYPE netyylval;
  size_t curr_lineno = 0;

# define yylval netyylval

/* Max size of string constants */
# define MAX_STR_CONST 4097
# define MAX_CWD_SIZE 4097
# define YY_NO_UNPUT   /* keep g++ happy */



/* define YY_INPUT so we read thorugh readline */
/* # undef YY_INPUT */
/* # define YY_INPUT(buf, result, max_size) result = get_input(buf, max_size); */


char string_buf[MAX_STR_CONST]; /* to assemble string constants */
char *string_buf_ptr = string_buf;


/*
 *  Add Your own definitions here
 */

 bool string_error = false;

 inline bool put_char_in_buf(char c)
 {
   if (string_buf_ptr == &string_buf[MAX_STR_CONST - 1])
     {
       yylval.error_msg = "String constant too long";
       string_error = true;
       return false;
     }
   *string_buf_ptr++ = c;
   return true;
 }

%}

%x STRING

/*
 * Define names for regular expressions here.
 */
/* Keywords */
LOAD         [lL][oO][aA][dD]
SAVE         [sS][aA][vV][eE]
RIF          [rR][iI][fF]
COD          [cC][oO][dD]
EXIT         [eE][xX][iI][tT]

DIGIT           [0-9]
UPPER_LETTER    [A-Z]
LOWER_LETTER    [a-z]
ANY_LETTER      ({UPPER_LETTER}|{LOWER_LETTER})
SPACE           [ \f\r\t\v]
NEWLINE         \n

INTEGER         {DIGIT}+
ID              {INTEGER}
VARNAME         {ANY_LETTER}([_\.-]|{ANY_LETTER}|{DIGIT})*

%%

{SPACE}  /* Ignore spaces */ 

{NEWLINE} { ++curr_lineno; return NEWLINE; }

 /*
  * Keywords are case-insensitive except for the values true and false,
  * which must begin with a lower-case letter.
  */
{LOAD}       return LOAD; 
{SAVE}       return SAVE;
{RIF}        return RIF;
{COD}        return COD;
{EXIT}       return EXIT;

 /*
  * The single-characters tokens 
  */
[=;]          return *yytext;


 /*
  *  String constants (C syntax)
  *  Escape sequence \c is accepted for all characters c. Except for 
  *  \n \t \b \f, the result is c.
  *
  */

\" { /* start of string */
  string_buf_ptr = &string_buf[0];
  string_error = false;
  BEGIN(STRING); 
} 
<STRING>[^\\\"\n\0] {
  if (not put_char_in_buf(*yytext))
    return ERROR;
 }
<STRING>\\\n {  // escaped string
  if (not put_char_in_buf('\n'))
    return ERROR;
  ++curr_lineno;
 } 
<STRING>\\n {
  if (not put_char_in_buf('\n'))
    return ERROR;
 }
<STRING>\\t {
  if (not put_char_in_buf('\t'))
    return ERROR;
 }
<STRING>\\b {
  if (not put_char_in_buf('\b'))
    return ERROR;
 }
<STRING>\\f {
  if (not put_char_in_buf('\f'))
    return ERROR; 
}
<STRING>\\\0 {
  yylval.error_msg = "String contains escaped null character.";
  string_error = true;
  return ERROR;
 }
<STRING>{NEWLINE} {
  BEGIN(INITIAL);
  ++curr_lineno;
  yylval.error_msg = "Unterminated string constant";
  return ERROR;
 }
<STRING>\" { /* end of string */
  *string_buf_ptr = '\0';
  BEGIN(INITIAL);  
  if (not string_error)
    {
      yylval.symbol = strdup(string_buf); // TODO: ojo con este memory leak
      return STRCONST;
    }
 }
<STRING>\\[^\n\0ntbf] {
  if (not put_char_in_buf(yytext[1]))
    return ERROR; 
 }
<STRING>'\0' {
  yylval.error_msg = "String contains escaped null character.";
  string_error = true;
  return ERROR;
 }
<STRING><<EOF>> {
  yylval.error_msg = "EOF in string constant";
  BEGIN(INITIAL);
  return ERROR;
 }

{ID} { // matches integer constant 
  yylval.symbol = yytext;
  return ID;  
}

{VARNAME} {
  yylval.symbol = yytext;
  return VARNAME;
}

. {
  cout << "LEX ERROR" << endl;
  yylval.error_msg = yytext;
  return ERROR; 
 }
%%

int yywrap()
{
  return 1;
}

extern int yyparse();

string get_prompt(size_t i)
{
  stringstream s;
  s << i << " > ";
  return s.str();
}

int main()
{

  for (size_t i = 0; true; ++i)
     {
       string prompt = get_prompt(i);
       char * line = readline(prompt.c_str());
       if (line == nullptr)
     break;

       YY_BUFFER_STATE bp = yy_scan_string(line);
       yy_switch_to_buffer(bp);
       free(line);

       int status = yyparse();

       cout << "PARSING STATUS = " << status << endl;

       yy_delete_buffer(bp);
     }
}
```

As possibly seen, a big part of the lexer is dedicated to recognized string constants. I do not know if this lexer is perfect and elegant, but I could say that I tested it intensively and that it works.

Now, when the program is called,this is a trace:

```
0 > load "name"
ERROR syntax error 
PARSING STATUS = 1
1 >
```

That is, the grammar, which surely is specified wrongly, fails to recognize the rule

```
cmd_unit: LOAD STRCONST
```

Well, although it is sure that I do not dominate the world of grammars, I have dedicated some important time for understanding this little and simple specification and I do not still manage to understand why it fails to parse a very single rule. I'am almost sure that it is a silly mistake, but I do know which is.

So, I would really be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is here:

```
{NEWLINE} { ++curr_lineno; return NEWLINE; }
```

I'm not sure how this even compiles, since `NEWLINE` is not defined as a token. I don't see any definition for it anywhere (pattern macros don't count since they are resolved before the generated scanner is produced.)

Since your grammar is expecting `'\n'` as a token value for a newline character, that's what you need to return:

```
{NEWLINE} { ++curr_lineno; return '\n'; }
```

---

Solving problems like this without debugging aids can be tricky. Fortunately, both flex and bison come with debugging options which make it extremely simple to see what is going on (and avoid the necessity to include your own tracing messages in bison actions).

For flex, use the `-d` flag when you generate the scanner. That will print copious information about the progress of the scanner. (In this case, that seems like the most likely place to start, anyway.)

For bison, use the `-t` flag when you generate the parser and set the global variable `yydebug` to a non-zero value. Since bison tracing is contingent on the setting of the `yydebug` global variable (whose default value is 0), you can just add the `-t` flag to your bison invocation, so that you don't have to regenerate the file to turn tracing off.

---

Note: In your `ID` and `VARNAME` rules, you insert `yytext` into your semantic value:

```
yylval.symbol = yytext;
```

That won't work. `yytext` is only valid until the next call to `yylex`, and so by the time the bison action which uses the semantic value is executed, the string pointed to by `yytext` will have changed. (This is likely to be true even if the bison action only refers to the last token in the right-hand side, because bison normally reads a lookahead token before deciding to execute a reduction.) You must copy the token (using, for example, `strdup`) and remember to free it when you don't need the value any more.

---

A note on style. Just a personal opinion, ignore at will:

Personally, I find overuse of pattern macros distracting. You could just write that rule as:

```
\n        { ++curr_lineno; return '\n'; }
```

Similarly, instead of defining, for example, `DIGIT`, `UPPER_LETTER`, etc., you could use Posix-standard character classes:

```
INTEGER   [[:digit:]]+
VAR_NAME  [[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_.-]*
```

(There is no need to backslash escape <kbd>.</kbd> in a character class.)

Comment: Thanks a lot @rici. However, I have done all your suggested mods and it does not work yet. I do not manage to understand why it fails to recognise the second rule for `cmd_unit`. A have done a test without readline, passing it the string constant `load \"name\"" and it still fails

Comment: @lrleon: It probably wouldn't hurt to use the error messages you produce :) Otherwise, you're more or less flying blind, ¿no? Why don't you enable flex and bison tracing, so that you can see what is actually going on? For flex, just use the `-d` flag when you generate the scanner. (That seems like the most likely place to start, anyway.) For bison, use the `-t` flag when you generate the parser *and* set the global variable `yydebug` to a non-zero value.

Comment: fixed! Your suggestion allowed me to trace the error source. The header `net-parser.H` contained a `enum yytokentype` which numbers conflicted with the `%token` specification. Again, thanks! and yes I am a blind bird, because my experience with compilers does not go beyond school exercises